# Is it possible to print this shape without printing spaces in C++ as described in the book "Think Like Programmer" by Anton Spraul?

Tags: c++, cout

In a book named ["Think Like a Programmer" by Anton Spraul](https://nostarch.com/thinklikeaprogrammer), on chapter 2, exercise 1, page 53, this is what is written:

> Using the same rule as the shapes programs from earlier in the chapter
> (only two output statements — one that outputs the hash mark and one
> that outputs an end-of-line), write a program that produces the
> following shape:
>
> ```
> ########
>  ######
>   ####
>    ##
> ```

So we can only use `cout << "\n";` and `cout << "#";` but not `cout << " ";`

Solving this problem by printing spaces is easy (see code below). **But is it possible to print such shape without printing spaces in C++?**

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    int shapeWidth = 8;

    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
        for(int spaceNum = 0; spaceNum < row; spaceNum++) {
            cout << " ";
        }
        for(int hashNum = 0; hashNum < shapeWidth-2*row; hashNum++) {
            cout << "#";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

Solving this problem by printing spaces is easy (see code above). **But is it possible to print such shape without printing spaces in C++?**

In one of the answers I read one can remove the `for (int spaceNum. . .` loop and rather just put `cout << setw(row+1);` to achieve that.

**Clarification:** The author never used a shape as example where one had to print spaces or indentations like the above. Interpreting the exercise above literally, he expects us to write that shape by printing "#" and "\n" only. Printing spaces or indentations by only printing "#" and "\n" seems not possible to me, so I thought maybe he was not careful when he wrote exercises. Or there's a way to achieve that but it's just me who doesn't know. This is why I asked this.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to instruct the console to print padding without explicitly saying `cout << " ";`? You might be interested in [std::setw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) but there'll still be spaces in the output. I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: When I see a question like this, I tend to ask myself: do I want to see the solution on a code review, or do I want to come across the solution while debugging the code during a grave prod issue at 3AM? Don't get me wrong, it's not your fault: it's the book's, but the answer is usually a big NO. Instead, use simple solutions that express what you'd like to do (i.e., your code that you copied).

Comment: I suspect that there are hints in "the shapes programs from earlier in the chapter", about which we know nothing.

Comment: Do non-printing characters (i.e. characters that are not ASCII code 32, but nevertheless are rendered as only whitespace) count, or is that considered cheating?  :)

Comment: how did Anton print spaces without printing spaces in the earlier exercises?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number he did not print spaces or indentations in earlier "example" exercises.

Comment: I don't think this depends at all on the language but on the console to which output is being sent. The C++ program will just send characters to the console. If that console has the ability to display those shapes without using spaces (as most consoles will), then you can do it using any language, C++ being no exception.
I think the question needs to specify what console is being used, rather than the language.

Comment: See `setw` in [Input/output manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.
Set the stream **width** to the length of the row.
Set the stream formatting to right-justified.

Look up stream manipulators in your book or another C++ references.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly! But that is a question about the system you’re running on, not about C++. As far as the language is concerned, it’s just outputting characters. The fact that outputting a “space” character moves the cursor to the right on the screen — or even the existence of the screen — is a matter of how the operating system and the software running on it interpret the characters that have been output.

Most notably, you can use [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to move the cursor around on most text consoles. There’s no particular reason to do this unless you’re writing a full-screen text mode UI.